# Using CSS hover on iPhone / iPad for dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating a div dynamically which will be used with css hover.

```
$('<div />', { id: 'idA', class: 'myclass' })
```

Using CSS hover for iPhone / iPad will not translate them into a click event. I read that by using the onclick return true event within the div could resolve this issue.

**My question:** is it a good idea to create the div as below?

```
$('<div />', { id: 'idA' , class: 'myclass', onClick: 'return true' })
```

Comment: That might work (I have read as well) but it's a bit hacky to use inline JavaScript for this. The issue is more likely to be related to the fact that the element is created dynamically. To register a click on it, you probably need a delegated event. https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: what @Shikkediel said. Using event delegation will also give you performance improvement  - or - will prevent performance deterioration in case you create a lot of dynamic `div` elements

Answer (score 0):

Why to complicate the code so much? More readable version:

```
$('<div></div>')
.attr('id','idA')
.addClass('myclass')
.on('click',function(){return true;});
```